# mathtools: How to center formulas inside \splitdfrac?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\dfrac{x}{\splitdfrac{a_1 a_2 a_3}{b_1 b_2 b_3}}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The two lines at the bottom part of the equation are not horizontally aligned right. I need them to be centered. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: From looking at the `mathtools` manual (https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), this is probably by design.

Comment: Related: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17934

Comment: Why do you encase the equations in `gathered` environments?

Comment: The idea behind `\splitdfrac` is to help readers in understanding that the text is to be considered a single unit. With centering, your readers will have a hard time in interpreting the output. Or is it for a different purpose than fractions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `\splitdfrac` or even `\splitfrac` -- just encase the two-line denominator in a `matrix` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{\begin{matrix}
            a_1 a_2 a_3 \\ 
            b_1 b_2 b_3
         \end{matrix}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: He'll must freeze over before I revert an edit of you :). I go offline now, it's past midnight for me.

Comment: @yegor256 -- In case you're curious what the main difference between the solutions that use `gathered` and `matrix` for the denominator material may be: the former solution typesets its contents in displaymath style, while the latter use inline-math style. What's more appropriate depends, of course, on the material in the denominator.

Answer (score 5):

Based on https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17934.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \frac{x}{\splitdfrac{a_1 a_2 a_3}{b_1 b_2 b_3}}
\end{equation}

% https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17934
\begin{equation}
   \frac{x}{
        \begin{gathered}
          a_1 a_2 a_3\\
          b_1 b_2 b_3
        \end{gathered}
        }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of simplifying the equations by removing the "outer" `gathered` environments. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\atop` primitive:

```
$$
  {x \over \displaystyle{\mathstrut a_1 a_2 a_3\atop b_1 b_2 b_3}}
$$
```

Answer (score 3):

You might catch two birds with one stone:

1. fix the definition of `\splitdfrac` so it leaves appropriate vertical space when used in a denominator (at least when the first line is not too tall);
2. add a *-version that does centering of the items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\splitdfrac}{smm}{%
  \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}
    {\mathstrut#2\IfBooleanF{#1}{\quad\hfill}}% top
    {\IfBooleanF{#1}{\hfill\quad}\mathstrut#3}% bottom
}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{x}{\splitdfrac{a_1 a_2 a_3}{b_1 b_2 b_3}}
\quad
\dfrac{x}{\splitdfrac*{a_1 a_2 a_3}{b_1 b_2 b_3}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If you're running a version of LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01 you will need to add `\usepackage{xparse}`.

[image]

However, if confronted with the output of the *-version, I'd probably be puzzled about its interpretation.